# How to select date from PickerWheel on browser UI similar to iOS style using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I am trying to select start and end dates from PickerWheel on the browser. But click and select methods are not working. Because to select date we need to move like in iOS devices date picker wheel. I would like to automate to pick up the next day to search.

URL - https://carshare.rakuten.co.jp/

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Just an FYI, the select method in Selenium will not work for this because the website is not using <select>, it's using <ul>. See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/select_lists/

Comment: @LeeJensen, thank you for your response. But is there any workaround to select a date from this form?

Comment: There's no built-in method for picking an element in a UL/LI element. You have to write that method yourself. Unless you can get the developer to use Select instead.